# simplePagination preventDefault on page click

Tags: jquery, pagination, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm using [this plugin](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) to create a pagination. On page click I have my function but I don't want the page to add `#page-1` to the URL. How can I prevent that?

`preventDefault` not working because I can't catch the event.

```
$('#pagination').pagination({
    items: items,
    displayedPages: 3,
    edges: 1,
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
        // my function
    }
);
```

Comment: I have seen the plugin.May I know why do you want to do this?It's by the feature of the plugin.

Comment: my site is a single page application. i don't want changes in my url.

Comment: ok then please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1):

it is so simple!

```js
 onPageClick: function (page, event) {
    event.preventDefault() 
  // my function
 }
```